# Based on CASE Pivot multiple rows into single row and multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose there is a table

```
NAME   Unit   Date      Time   Type LOAD
A1Cu    2   2020-01-02  10:30   CU  0.1
A1Ta    5   2020-01-02  10:30   TA  0.3
A1Ch    6   2020-01-02  10:30   CH  0.2
B1Ch    4   2020-02-15  11:40   CH  0.52
B1Ta    8   2020-02-15  11:40   TA  0.83
C1Ta    5   2020-06-18  21:00   TA  0.11
Z1Ch    8   2020-08-08  15:30   CH  0.24
D1Ta    8   2020-06-18  01:30   TA  0.3
C1Cu    6   2020-06-18  21:00   CU  0.2
```

Then for same date and time merge multiple rows into single column by applying following logic

```
FOR NAME AND UNIT (Stop when one of the condition is met)
IF Type CU Then take NAME & UNIT 
ELSE IF Type CH Then take NAME & UNIT
ELSE IF Type TA Then take NAME UNIT

For Load Put in respective column
```

The final Result should be like

```
NAME   Unit   Date      Time  TypeCULoad TypeCHLoad TypeTALoad
A1Cu    2   2020-01-02  10:30     0.1         0.2       0.3
B1Ch    4   2020-02-15  11:40     NULL        0.52      0.83
C1Cu    6   2020-06-18  21:00     0.2         NULL      0.11
Z1Ch    8   2020-08-08  15:30     NULL        0.24      Null
D1Ta    8   2020-06-18  01:30     NULL        NULL      0.3
```

I have the partial solution but finding it hard to get Name and Load Logic right:

```
SELECT Date, Time,[TypeCULoad], [TypeCHLoad ],[TypeTALoad] FROM
(
SELECT 
Date, Time, col, val FROM(
 SELECT *, 'Type'+Type+'Load' as Col, Load as Val FROM TESTAIR 
) t
) tt
PIVOT ( max(val) for Col in ([TypeCULoad], [TypeCULoad],[TypeCULoad]) ) AS pvt

Result
   Date         Time  TypeCULoad TypeCHLoad TypeTALoad
   2020-01-02   10:30     0.1         0.2       0.3
   2020-02-15   11:40     NULL        0.52      0.83
   2020-06-18   21:00     0.2         NULL      0.11
   2020-08-08   15:30     NULL        0.24      Null
   2020-06-18   01:30     NULL        NULL      0.3
```

Need help on Name and Load?

Comment: Please add details what you have tried so far. Nobody here is to write query for anyone.

Comment: @gotqn as mentioned in the logic for name and unit..CH comes before TA so name and load is B1CH...if there would have been CU then B1CU would have preference...

Comment: @iVad  sorry mate was about to update with my findings. Didn't realize will get response so early. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Why you keep A1Cu from A1Cu, A1Ta and A1Ch? What is the logic?

Comment: @mkRabbani logic is based on type preference..1st pref to cu then ch then ta..logic is mentioned in the question. Thanks

Comment: please explain more on your `merge logic`. It is not clear and confusing. The result for all condition are the same `take NAME & UNIT`. The grouping, Is it also based on first 2 characters of `NAME` ?

Answer (score 0):

First try to get the desired results before applying `PIVOT`

```
with cte as
(
 SELECT name, unit, date, time, 'Type' + Type + 'Load' as Col, Load as Val, Type, LEFT(name, 2) xxx,
 RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(name, 2) ORDER BY CASE type WHEN 'CU' THEN 1 WHEN 'CH' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END) dd
 FROM TESTAIR 
)
select name, unit, Date, Time, [TypeCULoad], [TypeCHLoad ], [TypeTALoad] from
(
select b.name, b.unit, a.date, a.time, a.col, a.val
from cte a
 join cte b on a.xxx = b.xxx and b.dd = 1
) f
PIVOT (max(val) for Col in ([TypeCULoad], [TypeCHLoad],[TypeTALoad]) ) AS pvt
```